# How to wire a three-prong extension cord to 110 outlet?

Tags: electrical

I have a 1000w inverter wired to a 12v DC battery. The inverter has two GFCI 110 outlets on it. I want to run an extension-style cord from the inverter receptacle but cut off one end and wire a standard 110 outlet.

I saw [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29715/is-it-safe-to-wire-regular-receptacles-to-the-end-of-an-extension-cord) which asks if something along these lines is *safe*, but I'm wonder how exactly to achieve it. Do I need a special type or gauge electrical cord? A certain outlet box? Do I need a GFCI  outlet? Can I use the ground wire in the extension cord to ground the outlet?

Comment: You can use the ground wire but there is no information on the size 15 or 20 amp. These need 14 or 12 awg . Other than this We are just guessing from the information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, it's not cost effective compared with buying extension cords with multiple outlets on the far end, or 2 extension cords, or a 3-1 adapter or several other options.  You need:

- Extension cord (14ga at least; 12ga if using 20A receptacles)  $10-30
- listed steel strain relief for your cord and 1/2" knockout - $3
- 4" 2-gang all steel box $2
- 2-gang 2 or 4 outlet steel box cover $2
- 1 or 2 duplex receptacles, $1-4
- 1 foot black, white, green solid core 12ga wire, $1
- 3 wire nuts, red  $1

Put 6" pigtails on each of the receptacles using side screws or clamp-and-screw (found on better receptacles).  Lop the extension cord and push the strain relief down it, gasket side out.  Knock out a 1/2" hole on the 2-gang box and bolt the strain relief through it, gasket out.  Wire-nut the 3 black wires together, ditto white and green/bare, careful as you are mixing solid and stranded.  Cram everything into the box and button it up. Test carefully, done.

You need at least 14ga wire if you have 15A outlets and 12ga wire if any 20A outlets.  Doing this with 16ga is unsafe.

A GFCI outlet is a good idea, you can slave the second duplex outlet off the "load" side.   If you don't use a GFCI, you must attach the cable ground to the outlet, that will attach it to the metal box, but test this just the same.

Comment: Am I missing the part about the white wire going to the wide slit and the hot (red/black) wire going to the narrow slit?